# Order by clause fails if upper case specified in select

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(LEFT(title, 1)) as title
 FROM <table_name>
 ORDER BY LEFT(title, 1);
```

which fails with an error

> #3065 - Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'title' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

This works fine when using UPPER in Order by like `ORDER BY UPPER(LEFT(title, 1));`

I want to know why it fails before as order by is case-insensitive by default I guess as mentioned here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html

I'm on MySQL 5.7+ with all default sql_modes enabled

Answer (score 1):

I think the error message is pretty clear.  The error arises because `title` could either refer to the column in the table or to the column alias.  The search looks first for the column, so the query is interpreted as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(LEFT(t.title, 1)) as title
FROM <table_name> t
ORDER BY LEFT(t.title, 1);
```

I think you can fix this by using a different alias:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(LEFT(t.title, 1)) as new_title
FROM <table_name> t
ORDER BY LEFT(new_title, 1);
```

Comment: yeah, That works, but if I have different alias name (let's say `title_alias`) in my above query - it fails :(. I still then have to mention `UPPER(LEFT(title, 1))` in my order clause. Can I please know the reason why this doesn't work with `LEFT(title, 1)` with alias name being different ?

Comment: is order by concerned with the case selected in select statement ?

Comment: @jitendrapurohit . . . I think I explain the issue with the alias -- it is confused with a column name and the column name takes precedence.